# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: users, form, upload, user-profile

I created a form on the frontend that allows users to upload their profile photos:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="users/{{ currentUser.username }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    <input type="file" name="photo">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

But I get the following error:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed from /Users/rain/dev/valet/tr3ndsideas/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/serializers/PhpSerializer.php

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Craft 3?  There was a similar bug fixed in RC14 around entries and entry types: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#fixed-2 Can you enable devMode and share the full stack trace leading up to the error?

Comment: @BradBell devMode is enabled, but where is the tracing file? Sorry, a noob I'm and totally new to craft...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem which is because of a plugin called "Scout". I just update it and everything seems to be fine now.